# Typescript error: is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'. Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, children

I created a curved container and I'm trying to use it in my project, but an error is reported and I don't know how to solve it, does anyone have any ideas?

```
import Image from "next/image";
import curveImage from "/public/curve.png";
import curveReverseImage from "/public/curve-reverse.png";
import curveImageBlack from "/public/curve-black.png";
import curveReverseImageBlack from "/public/curve-reverse-black.png";

type Props = {
  children: JSX.Element;
  curveTop?: "white" | "black" | "none";
  curveBottom?: "white" | "black" | "none";
  [defaultParam: string]: any;
};

export default function CurvedContainer({
  children,
  curveTop = "white",
  curveBottom = "white",
  ...rest
}: Props) {
  return (
    <div {...rest} className={`${rest.className} flex flex-col`}>
      {curveTop != "none" && (
        <div className="curveTop" style={{ marginTop: -1 }}>
          <Image
            height="250"
            alt="top image"
            src={
              curveTop == "white" ? curveReverseImage : curveReverseImageBlack
            }
          />
        </div>
      )}

      {children}

      {curveBottom != "none" && (
        <div className="curveTop -mb-2">
          <Image
            height="250"
            alt="top image"
            src={curveBottom == "white" ? curveImage : curveImageBlack}
          />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I don't know why this error shows up unfortunately. If someone could help me that would be really dope!

```
 <Container
    className="none"
    curveTop="white"
    curveBottom="none"
  >
    <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-center p-8">
      <a href="#" className={`bg-black text-white font-bold
         tracking-wider text-sm text-center uppercase rounded-full px-8 py-2 shadow-lg `}
        type="button">
        Saiba Mais
      </a>
    </div>
 </Container>
```

error here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your `Container` Component has an attribute `children`, `curveTop` and `curveBottom`
When you call the `Container` Component you dont pass `children`. try to pass this prop too.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use `React.ReactNode` type for react elements as it also works for array of elements.
Simply change your type

```
children: JSX.Element;
```

to `React.ReactNode`

Comment: i tried but the error persists,same mistake,  any other ideas?